# How to (or should you) add "CS concepts" like Graphs or Image Processing in a programmer's CV?

Tags: resume

In a programmer's CV, you normally add a list of technologies you've been using.

Should you also include that you've had experience (and are interested in) working with specific areas of Computer Science, such as Graphs, Image Processing, Sound Analysis, etc (as opposed to writing general CRUD and business rules)?

How could you name the category to list those? "CS concepts"? "Areas of interest"?

I've seen once a job offer requiring "algorithms", which got me confused for sounding very general. But I suspect they mean something like "that which is not general CRUD and business rules", including not so specific concepts like data structures and big-O notation.

How could we communicate this better?

Comment: Are you a fresher or a professional with experience?

Comment: Professional wIth 5y experience

Answer (score 1):

List the jobs you've done, or documents you've published, in which you applied those concepts.(Serious contribution to an open-source project can be treated as a publication.) If you're a newbie and don't have any publications or work history, you may want to call out the specific classes or (better) sequences of classes you took specializing in those ideas as part of your education section.

Remember that most of us have had exposure to these concepts; to impress folks you need to have done something serious and interesting with them or done some advanced study in them.

"Areas of interest" is usually taken to mean "I'm particularly interested in an opportunity to work in these areas". It doesn't necessarily imply that you have a head start on those topics.

Answer (score 0):

Usually at the top of the resume you have a section for skills that lists these things. However, I would say it depends on what job you're going for. For example, Graph coloring might apply to logistic companies looking for ways to improve their delivery. They may also apply to businesses such as delivery routes, etc. Graph coloring would otherwise just be a "interest" point but of no use for a business such as that of a typical web company.

Your resume should say one specific goal you're trying to state. It is basically saying you're trying to get into something specific. A generic resume, while sounding great, is really all over the place. For example, "Looking for a rewarding career in web development" vs "Looking for rewarding career in software development improving delivery" vs "Looking for a job doing something that relates to something I got a degree in."